# Is it possible use an rvalue to initialize a data member?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm very new to r-value references and move semantics but the tutorials I've read have the attitude "since the temporary is a perfectly well constructed object that's usually copied and destroyed, why not extend its lifetime and move it around?"

So I'm picturing a scenario like this:

```
class Foo
{
  Foo m_foo; // Could also be a reference or a unique_ptr of any sort
public:
  Foo() {}
  Foo(Foo &&v_foo) { /*initialize m_foo using v_foo.*/ }

};

int main() 
{
  auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>( Foo() );
  return 1;
}
```

Is anything like this possible?

**Update:** For clarification, what I mean when I say "initialize m_foo using v_foo" is I'd like to have `m_foo` point to or reference the `v_foo` object (the temporary created in main). Not copy/move its fields, but have it become the member.

Comment: _I'd like to have m_foo point to or reference the v_foo object_ --> it is dangerous to have a pointer or reference to a temp object, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot keep a data member of type `Foo` inside class `Foo` because the object would be infinitely large (because each object of type `Foo` will have another `Foo` object inside, which that inner object will have another `Foo` object inside, and so on.

With this change, you can have something like this:

```
class Foo
{
   std::unique_ptr<Foo> m_foo; 
public:
   Foo() {}
   Foo(Foo &&v_foo) 
   { 
      m_foo = std::move(v_foo.m_foo); 
      v_foo.m_foo = nullptr;
   }

};

int main()
{
   auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know what move constructor usually looks like, I'm hoping to have the temporary created in main _become_  m_foo, not move its contents.

Comment: @NikosTsakas What do you mean by saying: "the temporary created in main become m_foo"? In general, if you want an object o1 to become object o2, you should either copy  o2 into o1 or move it.

Comment: In the case of this example, if I called the object declared as "auto foo" foo1, and the _temporary_ created as "Foo()" foo2: foo2's lifetime is extended as it is being passed as an rvalue reference. Is it possible to have m_foo point to or reference that same temporary foo2 extending its lifetime throughout the lifetime of the foo1 object without any copying or moving?

Comment: No. There is no way for a function parameter to extend the lifetime of a temporary used as its function argument, even if you did somehow know or assume it was originally a temporary.

Comment: Note this example code results in `foo->m_foo` containing a null pointer.

Comment: Thank you, this wasn't obvious to me for whatever reason. I'm accepting this answer, make a little edit if you'd like, so it's obvious you're answering the updated question.